# Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined from platojs using nodewebkit

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

I'm getting this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined from platoj  using  nodewebkit when trying to show the output result.
I'm trying to get  gaphic 
          ------------jsfile

```
   $scope.analyse = function() {

 $scope.db.select("project", {
            "id": {
              "value": $routeParams.id,
            },
          }).then(function(results) {
            for(i=0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
              //pour 
             console.log (results.rows.item(i).path);
      $scope.resultSource =  results.rows.item(i).path+ path.sep + 'output' + path.sep +'index.html'; 


         }
         }) 
         };

     $scope.init =function ()
   {
        $scope.db.select("project", {
            "id": {
              "value": $routeParams.id,
            },
          }).then(function(results) {
            for(i=0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {

  var files = results.rows.item(i).path+ path.sep +'www'+ path.sep + 'js'+'/*.js';

  var outputDir = results.rows.item(i).path+ path.sep +'output';
    // null options for this example
   var options = {
   title: 'test'
   };


    var callback = function (report){
    console.log (report);
    };
    plato.inspect(files, outputDir, {}, callback);
     }

      }) 
      }
```

--------------htmlfile

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-group">
             <h1></h1>
             <a class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="analyse()">Analyse</a>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div> 
 </div>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-group">
             <div ng-include="resultSource"></div>

           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>

   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Look like `lodash` not load.

Comment: who   fix   this ?   @stdob

Comment: provide more code please

Comment: @Silve2611 i provide u  more  code.thanks